# Copy non-adjacent cells and paste transpose but not to an entire row

Tags: excel, vba

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY62c.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7syF.png)

At the start of the code `TargetRow` has a value of 0. At the execution of `TargetRow = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`, value is 2. When the script reruns, `TargetRow` again starts at 0.

```
Sub TransferData()

Dim wsSource As Worksheet  'define source worksheet
Set wsSource = Worksheets("Form")

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet  'define target worksheet
Set wsTarget = Worksheets("DB")

Dim TargetRow As Long 'don't use Integer. Excel has more rows than Integer can handle.
TargetRow = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last used row + 1

'copy ticket data
wsSource.Range("TicketData").Copy
wsTarget.Range("F" & TargetRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

'copy scores
wsSource.Range("Scores").Copy
wsTarget.Range("Q" & TargetRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Whats the question?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanted to paste into the same row. So I suggest to first determine the next empty row only once and then using that for both copy/paste actions.

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet  'define source worksheet
Set wsSource = Worksheets("Form")

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet  'define target worksheet
Set wsTarget = Worksheets("DB")

Dim TargetRow As Long 'don't use Integer. Excel has more rows than Integer can handle.
TargetRow = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'last used row + 1

'copy ticket data
wsSource.Range("TicketData").Copy
wsTarget.Range("A" & TargetRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

'copy scores
wsSource.Range("Scores").Copy
wsTarget.Range("R" & TargetRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: I intend to assign this to a button so that when I click, the values from the "Form" sheet goes to the "DB" sheets in the next available row. and then clear the TicketData and Scores range, ready for the next set of data to be inputted.

Comment: Well, where is the problem then?

Comment: The script does not make the set of data go to the next available row. I badly need the data, ie, TicketData and Scores , to all go to the next empty rown. The script above pastes and overwrites on the same row.

Comment: This does paste to the empty row after the last used row. I don't understand what you mean because it does not overwrite anything. You need to be **much** more specific.

Comment: hmm...don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please see on top for the code I have on my workbook

Comment: Ok I can't edit the one on top. I practically copied your code :(                                            Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Set wsSource = Worksheets("Form")

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet  'define target worksheet
Set wsTarget = Worksheets("DB")

Dim TargetRow As Long 
TargetRow = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

wsSource.Range("TicketData").Copy
wsTarget.Range("F" & TargetRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

wsSource.Range("Scores").Copy
wsTarget.Range("Q" & TargetRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

Comment: If I make any changes to the source sheet and run the macro, it just goes to the same row and overwrites whatever was there before. I know your code is supposed to go to the next empty row, but for some reason it's not.

Comment: Please debug and go through the code step-by-step (using F8) and tell which value `TargetRow` has. Also edit your original question and add a screenshot of your sheet.